# Why state returned from my reducer is an empty object??(React-Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a problem in my redux reducer, it does not return expected state after dispatching `FETCH_BOOKS` action, it returns an empty object instead of an object of state which is books that is fetched by AJAX request,
the reducer returns correct data when storing my state in array instead of object, this is so confusing, why does this happen??

These are my components

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { bookReducer } from './reducers/BookReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

const middleware = [thunk];
const initialState = {};
const store = createStore(bookReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>   
  </Provider>, 
  document.getElementById('root')
);
registerServiceWorker();
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import BookShelf from './components/BookShelf'
import AllShelves from './components/AllShelves'
import Header from './components/Header';
import SearchPage from './components/SearchPage';
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI';
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {  

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.fetchBooks();
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.books)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Route exact path="/" component={AllShelves} />         
        <Route  path="/search" component={SearchPage} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
      books: state.books
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchBooks: () => {
       BooksAPI.getAll().then(books => dispatch({
         type: 'FETCH_BOOKS',
         books
       }))
    },

  }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App))
```

reducer that doesn't works

```
import { FETCH_BOOKS } from '../actions/Types.js';

import * as BooksAPI from '../BooksAPI'

const initialState = {
  books: [],
  query: ''
}

 export const bookReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
     case 'FETCH_BOOKS':
       return {
         ...state,   
         books: action.books,
       }
     default: 
       return state;
   }
}
```

The reducer that work

```
 export const bookReducer = (state = [], action) => {
   switch(action.type) {
     case 'FETCH_BOOKS':
       return action.books
     default: 
       return state;
   }
}
```

So why storing state in object doen't work and it works perfectly with array, i don't want to store my state in array, as books is not the only data i need to manage in my state!!!

Comment: I'm confused now! Which one is the one that works and which not?

Comment: sorry i edited it

Comment: Not sure about what are you intending to ask. You say state as an object doesn't work, but the working reducer example returns state as an object. And for the not working reducer you are returning an array for the state.
If you look at you action, you are returning data as payload but in the reducer you are trying to return `action.books` which obviously is undefined. You need to return `action.payload` like in the working reducer example.

Comment: @Vinit Sarvade i already edited that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've checked all your codes and I think the problem possibly come from the redux store setup:

```
const initialState = {};
const store = createStore(bookReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
```

I suggest removing the initialState:

```
const initialState = {};    // remove this line cuz we don't need it
const store = createStore(bookReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware)); //fixed like this
```

In addition, I think you should fetch your books in the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook instead of `componentWillMount()`, like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchBooks();
}
```

Comment: can you please explain why didMount instead willMount??
@ Nguyễn Thanh Tú

Comment: It's might inconvenient to explain here, however, I think after reading this article, you could figure it out yourself: [Where in the component lifecycle should I make an AJAX call?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 1):

In the second example, you are fetching the value in the reducer as `action.books`, instead it should be `action.payload` because that's the key dispatched in action.

Comment: i edited the question, sorry i changed payload to books

Answer (score 0):

After any Action is dispatched you have to return a new state to the store so you have to return new state object for that you have to get the state now and change the books and return the new state so following code doing that

```
export const bookReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
 case 'FETCH_BOOKS':
   return {
     ...state,   
     books: action.books,
   }
 default: 
   return state;
}
}
```

but from the other reducer you return only the books array that coming from the action that is wrong way to do that